# Accessing Quandl data call from SAS using url method

Tags: url, web, sas, time-series, quandl

I was trying accessing Quandl(http://www.quandl.com) data. Quandl is an open website from where we can download readiliy available curated time-series data on many financial and economic topics. They have build it in such a manner that you can call it through R/Matlab/Eviews/Python etc. I was trying from SAS. When I tried website Normal csv download call for Quandl data "FRED/MSWP5" without any date condition it works fine and I am able to create SAS dataset.
code is as below:

```
filename DAAA url "http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/MSWP5.csv?";
data BY_AAA(drop=dd);
length dd $10;
format date date9.;
infile DAAA dlm="," dsd;
input dd$ value;
date=input(dd,yymmdd10.);
if not missing(date) then output;
run;
```

success log:

```
NOTE: The data set WORK.BY_AAA has 152 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
  real time           0.88 seconds
  cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

But when I am trying to pass date condition with the same query it is giving error: 
new SAS code is as below: But I am able to achieve desired results with R/ Python/ Matlab with their respective code.

```
filename DAAA url "http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/MSWP5.csv? 
&trim_start=2000-07-01&trim_end=2013-02-01&sort_order=desc";
data BY_AAA(drop=dd);
length dd $10;
format date date9.;
infile DAAA dlm="," dsd;
input dd$ value;
date=input(dd,yymmdd10.);
if not missing(date) then output;
run;
```

it gives below error:

```
not working due to "&" sign is coming so SAS is saying
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference TRIM_START not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference TRIM_END not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference SORT_ORDER not resolved.
```

I understand that this is an issue related to escape character handle.
Can any body help me...I have tried below code also :

```
filename DAAA url "http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/MSWP5.csv?% 
26start_date=2012-07-01%26end_date=2013-02-01%26sort_order=desc" debug 
lrecl=8192;
```

In this case no SAS log is coming, a blank dataset with 0 observation is getting created.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not errors, per se.  They're a note that you are writing something that looks like a macro variable; however, if they are not defined as a macro variable, they will still be passed forward as text including the & sign.  I ran your code and received results.

If you change your " " double quotes to ' ' single quotes, SAS will not attempt to resolve macro variables inside the string, and the warnings will disappear.

Comment: I just used single quote as below : filename DAAA url 'http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/MSWP5.csv?%26trim_start=2012-07-01%26trim_end=2013-02-01%26sort_order=desc' debug lrecl=8192; nothing is coming

Comment: ok now I got a log:NOTE: >>> GET
      /api/v1/datasets/FRED/MSWP5.csv?%26trim_start=2012-07-01%26trim_end=2013-02-01%26sort_order=desc
       HTTP/1.0
NOTE: >>> Host: www.quandl.com
NOTE: >>> Accept: */*.
NOTE: >>> Accept-Language: en
NOTE: >>> Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1,*,utf-8
NOTE: >>> User-Agent: SAS/URL
NOTE: >>>
NOTE: <<< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
NOTE: <<< Cache-Control: no-cache

NOTE: <<< Connection: close

NOTE: <<< Content-Type: text/html

NOTE: <<< 

ERROR: Bad request. Use the debug option for more info.
but what I can do now ?

Comment: You need to debug the web query, this isn't a SAS issue.

Comment: Use single quotes and try removing the first ampersand after the question mark in the URL you are calling.

Comment: http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/MSWP5.csv?trim_start=2012-07-01&trim_end=2013-02-01 this webquery if you put in any browser address bar it works, but the same thing when I am trying through SAS using http method it fails, I have put single quote, I have tried removing the first ampersand after the question mark, also I have encoded it using %26 so my query is as below filename DAAA url 'http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/MSWP5.csv?trim_start=2012-07-01%26trim_end=2013-02-01' debug lrecl=8192;